# C# - Process is not exiting when called using Process object

Tags: c#, cmd

I am using Process object in C# to launch my C++ binaries to perform some operations.
Previously I was using File name as "cmd.exe" with "\c my_arguments > File.txt" as arguments.

It was showing some issue like exiting with Non-zero Exit code.
I observed that the cmd.exe is still running after crash. (from Task manager).

I am using redirection in arguments to get all text in file. The C++ binary works fine when called manually from command prompt.

Note :-
1) My binary prints approx 200-300 lines of text data on console
2) My binary calls another binary for validating results.

Approach 1 :-
File name as "Cmd.exe"
Observation :-
Sometimes the process gets exited with non-zero exit code with cmd.exe running in background. (Surprised to see this)

```
 Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + test.testExeName + " " + argument + " > " + test.testLogFileName;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = demoDest;
                p.Start();
```

Approach 2 :-
With File name :- "My C++ Binary"
Observation :-
The process doesn't get exited even task manager shows its running. It performs its operations when I called this but in validation part it got stuck where I have called another EXE file (Not sure, but I suspect on this step as all steps completed by my tests correctly before calling this another EXE).

```
Process p = new Process();

                    p.StartInfo.FileName = test.testExeName;
                    p.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    //p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = demoDest;
                    p.Start();
```

I am suspecting the issue is because of redirection of output. So planned to remove all console output by logging into file. If someone has faced this issue in past then please comment

Comment: So what is your question? Also, can you post the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Since the Process class can return the exit code for the process, it's quite possible that the process won't go away until you dispose of your "p" object.  In the underlying Windows (native) API, you can't get the exit code without having a handle to the process.  Once all the handles are closed, the process goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the original C++ EXE to log required results directly to file instead of console log redirection.
Now both the above specified approaches started to work fine.

Because of huge data redirection, the cmd process was getting stuck.
Now issue is resolved.